# $uibModalInstance is not defined

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working bootstrap modal directive . I need to open modal popup on ajax error method and popup is showing fine. but on button click inside modal , Where i need to dismiss modal , I am getting error

```
$uibModalInstance is not defined
```

First on module , I have registered correctly

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module("angularFormsApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

then on angular controller , I have injected this directive correctly.

```
var loginController = function ($scope, $window, $routeParams, $uibModal, DataService)
```

then I am calling this modal by following code inside same controller

```
var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.modalOptions.headerText = "Error";
        $scope.modalOptions.bodyText = reason.statusText;

        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: baseurl + 'app/ErrorMessages/PopUpErrorMessage.html',
            controller: 'loginController',
            scope: $scope
        });
    };

    $scope.cancelForm = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    };
```

Now as you can see I have created separate html file for modal and below is html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>{{modalOptions.headerText}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>{{modalOptions.bodyText}}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Close"
            ng-click="cancelForm()" />
</div>
```

Now When I click close button I am getting error

```
ReferenceError: $uibModalInstance is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.cancelForm (loginController.js:44)
```

Now I have gone though some different solution for same problem
Eg : http://plnkr.co/edit/6djuhA8ohMkrWW7zohg1?p=preview

But in this case above example is using two different controller  but in my case I am using same controller ,and If i inject both `$uibModal` as well as `$uibModalInstance` then  its not working

Answer (score 1):

Yes `uibModalInstance` will be undefined.
You need to store the reference of your uibmodel and call close on that reference. 
Like this :

```
var myModel = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: baseurl + 'app/ErrorMessages/PopUpErrorMessage.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        scope: $scope
    });
```

and in close function:

```
 $scope.cancelForm = function () {
    myModel.close();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to injected $uibModalInstance in your Controller as follows

```
var loginController = function ($scope, $window, $routeParams, $uibModal, DataService,$uibModalInstance)
```

Comment: If i add $uibModalInstance  then I am getting message 'Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance'

Comment: $uibModalInstance is avaialble in bootstarp version (0.14.3).As per my perception you might be not using bootstrap version(0.14.3).

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller from where you are opening modal, you need to inject the dependency $uibModal.
To open the modal you need to specify a html template, controller for the modal.

```
$scope.ErrorModal = function(index) {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: "/PopUpErrorMessage.html",
        controller: "popupErrorMsgController",
        controllerAs: "PEMCtrl",
        size: "md",
        resolve: {
          modalInstanceData: {
            headerText: "Error",
bodyText:reason.statusText
          }
        }
      });
      modalInstance.result.then(function(receivedObject) {
        //Modal closed
      });
```

Now in your Modal Controller -popupErrorMsgController you can access the modal instance by injecting $uibModalInstance. Also you can inject the other parameters which you want to resolve in your modal controller

```
       angular.module('yourApp')
            .controller('popupErrorMsgController', popupErrorMsgController);.
    popupErrorMsgController.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'modalInstanceData'];
        function popupErrorMsgController($scope, $uibModalInstance, modalInstanceData) {

$scope.modalInstanceData = modalInstanceData;
$scope.cancelForm = function(){
var objectToSend = {};
$uibModalInstance.close(objectToSend);
}
    }
```

In your modal controller you can assign the received parameters to the $scope of modal and access it inside your modal HTML template.

```
<h3>{{modalInstanceData.headerText}}</h3>
```

Hope this works for you!